How to generate a quadtree or octree scene map with HLOD structure from a 3D model? Please provide general steps
I need to partition a 3D model into an HLOD structure of a quadtree or octree, and then export this structure as 3dtiles, but I don't know how to partition it into an HLOD structure of a quadtree or octree.
I know how to divide a 3D model into quadtrees or octrees. When building a quadtree or octree, I limit the number of triangles in the nodes, which results in model data even for non leaf nodes. However, I don't know how to build an HLOD based on this type of tree.
